# How can I pass a List<string> as a parameter to a child component in blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

Parent Component

```
<MyChildComponent ParamList="{hello, world, this is great}"/>
```

Child Component

```
<ol>
    @foreach(string myParam in ParamList)
    {
        <li>@myParam</li>
    }
</ol>

@code {
[Parameter]
public List<string> ParamList {get;set;}
}
```

Expected Output

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. this is great
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong since I can't find anything in blazor docs about doing this. I'm not referring to splatting.

Comment: Something like this: `ParamList="@( new List<string> {"hello", "world", "this is great"} )"`

Comment: duh, so simple! I need to get better at razor syntax. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Nah, it's simple template syntax with c# embedded.

Comment: @daniherrera you should make this an answer, it's the nicest solution here IMO. Note you can also remove the outside set of quotes to make this expression even cleaner.

Comment: Awww @CraigBrown Be free to post an answer with this code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a variety of ways. This is one:

### MyChildComponent.razor

```
<ol>
@foreach (string myParam in ParamList)
{
    <li>@myParam</li>
}
</ol>

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public IReadOnlyList<string> ParamList { get; set; }
}
```

### Usage

```
<MyChildComponent ParamList="list" />

@code{

List<string> list =  new List<string> {"hello", "world", "Angular is great"};
}
```

Comment: What if the parents list is getted by an await async method?
In my case in the Parent component OnInitializedAsync, I await request the list to the api, and because of that the list is passed to child as null because parent is still fetching.. How can I Solve this?

Comment: you can override the OnParametersSetAsync() method and do your task.

Answer (score 1):

It dependes on what notation you prefer. If you want to keep the using side clean you could use a simple string and process it inside the component:

```
<MyChildComponent ParamList="hello, world, this is great"/>
```

...

```
<ol>
    @foreach(string myParam in ParamList.Split(',') )
    {
        <li>@myParam</li>
    }
</ol>
```

and the parameter is a simple `string`

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public string ParamList {get;set;}
}
```